# loading heavy js widgets causing the browser to stop responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I'm using an external js heavy widgets into my page which causing the browser to stop responding.
i want to create a delay between them to give time to loading by using `setTimeout`. But still load at the same time. I'm looking for a way to insert and load the widgets one by one.

```
function setWidgets(){
  var div = document.getElementById("content");
  var subDiv = div.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var id;
  var arr = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < subDiv.length; i++) {
    var elem = subDiv[i];
    if(elem.className == "info" ) {
      setTimeout( setWidget(elem) , 600);
    }
  }
}

function setWidget(elem) { 
  var para = elem.innerHTML.split(",");
  var divId = para[2];
  var widget = getWidget(para);
  var elemnt = document.getElementById(divId);

  $(elemnt).html(widget);
}

function getWidget(para){

  var pair = para[0];
  var frame = para[1];
  var elemId = para[2];
  var widget = [];

  widget.push(
    '<script>',
    '\n',
    "new TradingView.widget({",
    '\n',
    '"width": 512,',
    '\n',
    '"height": 288,',
    '\n',
    '"symbol": "FX:',
    pair,
    '",',
    '\n',
    '"interval":',
    '"',
    frame,
    '",',
    '\n',
    '"container_id": ',
    '"',
    elemId,
    '",',
    '\n',
    '"timezone": "exchange",',
    '\n',
    '"theme": "White",',
    '\n',
    '"style": "1",',
    '\n',
    '"toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",',
    '\n',
    '"hide_top_toolbar": true,',
    '\n',
    '"save_image": false,',
    '\n',
    '"hideideas": true',
    '\n',
    '});',
    '\n',
    '</',
    'script>'
  );

  return widget.join("");
}
```

Comment: What is `TradingView` ?

Comment: stock charts and a community of investors. and they have charting API and widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
setTimeout( setWidget(elem) , 600);
```

You call `setWidget` with elem and pass it result to the `setTimeout`. You need to pass function to `setTimeout` and it will call after delay:

```
setTimeout(function (elem) {
    setWidget(elem) 
}.bind(null, elem), 600);
```

But in this case you will start all `setTimeout`'s immediately, you need to make delay different:

```
setTimeout(function (elem) {
    setWidget(elem) 
}.bind(null, elem), 600 * (i + 1));
```

**Note: Also you need create a scope with current `elem`. I'm using `Function.prototype.bind` for it. If you need support for IE6-8 you can use `$.proxy` or create IIFE wrapper:**

```
  //create IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) wrapper
  //IIFE will create a new scope with needed variable elem
  setTimeout((function (elem) {
    return function () {
       setWidget(elem)
    }
  }(elem)), 600 * (i + 1));
```

Comment: Still! there is a delay first then all the widgets show up at the same time. thanks anyway

Comment: Can you create example with your edited code? Because my examples works fine

Comment: I just replaced my setTimeout() part with your second example. also i tried both. would you please share yours so i can test it.

Comment: :) I edited my answer, we just forgot to change delay in loop, without changing delay all `setTimeout`'s will call together

Comment: Great :) thanks you saved me. i have to study it. not clear to me!